# How to place the top left of a div element to the top right of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to place the top right of the div element friend_info to the top left of the button friend_button.

I have tried to use the code from https://javascript.info/coordinates#element-coordinates-getboundingclientrect but to no avail and I also tried to use this code:

```
var friend_button = document.getElementById("friend-button");
var friend_info = document.getElementById("friend_info");
friend_button.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
var coords = friend_button.getBoundingClientRect();
var coordsOfInfo = $('.friend_info').width();
var subtractWidth = coords.left-coordsOfInfo;
friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px";
friend_info.style.top = coords.top + "px";
friend_info.style.display = "block";
> });
friend_button.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
friend_info.style.display = "none";
> });
```

but the div element disdplays in the middle of the button instead of the left hand side. Here is the html and css for the code I am working on.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="Search_Media"><a href="Main_Page.html" class="Search-media">Search Media</a></h1>
            <div class="navigationbar">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="headings">
                <a class="active" href="Main_Page.html">Home</a>
                <a href="Messages.html">Messages</a>
                <a href="Friends.html">Friends</a>
                <a href="User_Info.html">User page</a>
            </div>
            <div class="friends">
                <h2>Friends</h2>
                <button type="button" class="friend-button" id="friend-button">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img src="default-pic.png" class="mr-3" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="mt-0">Friend1</h5>
                            <p>status: active</p>
                        </div>
                </button>
                <div class="friend_info" id="friend_info">
                    <video autoplay muted loop class="backgroundInfo">
                        <source src="Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-picture" alt="Default Picture" width="200" height="200">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <h1 class="Friend_Name">Friend1</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-1">
                                <h5>status: active</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-5">
                                <p class="info">Phone Number: 07914836605</p>
                                <p class="info">Name: Joe</p>
                                <p class="info">Surname: Smith</p>
                                <p class="info">Gender: Male</p>
                                <p class="info">Date of birth: 14/02/2003</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-grid">
                <div class="user-post">
                    Create post:<br>
                    <form>
                        <textarea id="create_post" rows="10" cols = "50"></textarea><br>
                        <input type="submit" class="post-button" value="Post">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="posts">
                    <div class="post">
                        <h3 id="existing_posts"><img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-pic" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">Posts</h3>
                        <p>This is an example of a post. It will need to be boxed and made so that the name of the user goes above
                            the name of the likes and dislikes of the posts are to the left of the post and that the reply and report
                            functionalities are at the bottom right of the posts. It will also need a box around it to show where the post starts and ends.</p>
                        <div class="options">
                            <a href="">Like</a>
                            <a href="">Comment</a>
                            <a href="" class="report">Report</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go To Top">Top</button>
        </div>
        <script src="Main_Page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.Search_Media{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
    z-index: 0;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.Search-media{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.Search-media:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.navigationbar{
    background-color: aqua;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top:15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -88.5px;
    color: black;
}

.headings{
    left:20.17%;
    height: 100;
    width: 200;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: black;
}
.headings a{
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
.headings a:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.headings a.active{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
}

.friend-button{
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.friend-button:hover{
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
}

.middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0% auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.middle-grid{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding-top: 37px;
    width: 50%;
}

.user-post{
    width: auto;
    margin: 0% auto;
}
.post-button{
    margin: 0% auto;
    color: black;
    padding-right: 50;
    padding-left: 50;
    padding-top: 5;
    padding-bottom: 5;
}
textarea{
    resize: none;
    color: black;
}

h3{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.posts{
    width:75%;
    text-align: left;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.post{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.post:nth-child(odd){
    color: black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 2;
}
.post p{
    margin-top: 5px;
}


.options{
    float: right;
}

.options .report{
    color: red;
}

h2{
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
.friends{
    position: fixed;
    right: 10%;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 15%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.media-body{
    text-align: left;
}

h5{
    font-size: 20;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 95%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0% auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 99; 
    border: none; 
    outline: none;
    background-color: red; 
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 15px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    font-size: 18px; 
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: darkred; 
}




.friend_info{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vh;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    top: 0px;
}


.backgroundInfo{
    position: inherit;
    z-index: -99;
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 600px;
    left: inherit;
    top: inherit;
}
.d-flex{
    color: white;
}

.Friend_Name{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
h5{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.info{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.p-5{
    border: 0%;
    width: auto;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 2rem !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the correct idea, but wrong execution. The correct javascript is the following:

```
var friend_button = document.getElementById("friend-button");
var friend_info = document.getElementById("friend_info");
friend_button.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    var coords = friend_button.getBoundingClientRect();
    var coordsOfInfo = $('.backgroundInfo').width();
    var subtractWidth = coords.left-coordsOfInfo;
    friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px";
    friend_info.style.top = coords.top + "px";
    friend_info.style.display = "block";
});
friend_button.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    friend_info.style.display = "none";
});
```

Notice how I changed which element I got the width off. I changed it to the backgroud width and now displays just how I want.